# What does this icon in SQL Server mean?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Can someone tell me what the icon of a server and a blue database symbol means. It is attached to database engine instance in my object explore view.

(I apologize, I am unable to add a image of the symbol at this time as I am new to stack overflow and am short two rep points needed to post images. If necessary when I cross the rep points threshold, I will attach an image.)

[Here is a picture](http://www.advess.net/media/database_server1.jpg)